# iOS embedded Youtube Player time change notification

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube-api

I am using YTPlayerView to play youtube video, which is wrapper of this Javascript API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference).

My app can be notified when user start/stop playing the video through the API, but I am wondering if my app can be notified for users' action to slide on the time bar that change the player's currentTime? I know that I can monitor using getCurrentTime API, but I want to get notified when currentTime is changed by user action, instead of monitoring it continuously.

Thanks for any suggestions